# excel 2003 vba syntax if and

Tags: excel, vba

Last used Excel VBA 5 years ago so rusty. Digitizing scans of births, marriages, deaths info as volunteer.
Searching a string for space (ascii 32), number (ascii 48-57), lowercase letter (ascii 97-122), number (ascii 48-57). With this string "Melton Mwbry 3a2852" and this code:

```
    If Asc(Mid(word, i, 1)) = 32 And Asc(Mid(word, i + 1, 1)) >= 48 And Asc(Mid(word, i + 1, 1) <= 57 _
    And Asc(Mid(word, i + 2, 1)) >= 97) And Asc(Mid(word, i + 2, 1)) <= 122 _
    And Asc(Mid(word, i + 3, 1)) >= 48 And Asc(Mid(word, i + 3, 1) <= 57) Then
```

The string is currently split at the first space rather than the second. I am obviously missing something important.

Comment: What exactly is your question? What does not work? Are you getting errors or something like that?

Answer (score 0):

It was missing closing brackets on the ascii text-doh! Sorry to have bothered everyone but I couldn't see for looking.